# The differences between the word "contradictory" and "ambivalent"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Correct me if wrong, I think both of the words are adjectives describing having two opposite characteristics at the same time.

To my understanding, while ambivalent is more of a psychological term or status, both contradictory and ambivalent can describe one's emotion, but only contradictory can describe things or facts. Also, contradictory is used to describe "to speak against". Are those statements correct?

EDIT:
Adding definition of the words according to the suggestion in the comments.
ps. I'm focusing on adjectives.

Contradictory

1. asserting the contrary or opposite; contradicting; inconsistent;
   logically opposite.
2. tending or inclined to contradict.

Ambivalent

1. having mixed feelings about someone or something; being unable to
   choose between two (usually opposing) courses of action
2. Psychology. of or relating to the coexistence within an individual
   of positive and negative feelings toward the same person, object, or
   action, simultaneously drawing him or her in opposite directions.

Comment: The dictionary definitions seem clear to me. Your second paragraph would be improved if you could include concrete examples of how you would use the words as you describe (or possibly, how you could **not** use them).

Comment: I think your initial assumption _is_ wrong. **Contradictory** describes the two opinions or characteristics which are opposed to one another. **Ambivalent** describes the feelings of a person who is drawn to two different points of view.

Comment: Someone wished to close the question for lack of research, presumably before the edit was made by the questioner. I suggest they now withdraw the close vote.

Comment: I agree with @Kate. Those words have little or no relationship with one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ambivalent" refers to one person not being able to choose from among several options, which may be opposite each other.

"contradictory" doesn't refer to a single person. It refers to multiple items that are opposite or inconsistent with each other. For instance, the Republican and Democratic parties are contradictory on many policies.

They can be related in some cases -- a person may be ambivalent if they receive contradictory information and can't decide which to believe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clue to difference in your chosen definitions. For *ambivalent* you quote “usually opposing”. Collins has:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ambivalent)
> *ambivalent*
> If you say that someone is ambivalent about something, they seem to be uncertain whether they really want it, or whether they really approve of it.
> *She remained ambivalent about her marriage.*
> Synonyms: undecided, mixed, conflicting, opposed

Your own quote and the Collins definition both point to *ambivalent* as being uncertain between two possibilities that may be, but are not necessarily, opposing. This is distinct from *contradictory*, which is by definition opposing.

“*She was ambivalent in her attitude to her marriage: she wondered if it was based on lust or love; it was certainly expedient and productive.*” In this example, love and lust are possibilities that are not contradictory; they may even coincide.